# Having totals at the bottom of a table in eclipse?

Tags: sql, eclipse

In [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/), I'm attempting to—

```
Select<some columns with sums and such>
From mytable
<Maybe some joins in there somewhere>
where <conditions>
Group By <Column with 9 rows>
order by <same column as Group By>
```

Now I'm trying to find the totals of all the columns there. To do this, however, I'm going into the actual table in eclipse. Adding an aggregation on the last row naming it the totals.

Results:

```
Location1   14,000
Totals      171,000
Location2   17,000
Totals      171,000
Location3   18,000
Totals      171,000
```

etc.

Is there a way to have the aggregation appear only on the bottom row, and only as one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would most likely do the aggregation as a separate query.  You could run both as separate queries and then union the results and display that.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized what I was doing wrong. I was placing the aggregation in a detail row, which is meant for the data in the query only. Placing a total in this row will get you the result I got before.

What you need to do is place the aggregation in a footer row. And that would fix it.